# List columns of table on which there is at least one row with a non null value for a specific query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find the proper query to :

> Get all the column names of a table on which there is at least one row with a non null value for a specific query.

Meaning : I will see which columns have at least one value set in the record returned by my given query.

I hope I'm clear enough.

Comment: Do you mean you want the column names? (Or the column values?)

Comment: @jarlh wanna get the column names to see which column has no value for my query

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a generic way to do this on several table.
I'm guessing this would probably be done using `user_tab_columns` table

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something as the following:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(col1) IS NOT NULL THEN 'COL1' END ||','
    || CASE WHEN MAX(col2) IS NOT NULL THEN 'COL2' END ||','
    ...
  FROM T
```

Then use REGEXP_REPLACE to replace duplicated `,`. You can use `user_tab_columns` to generate this query dynamically as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below anonymous block for your case , tablename should be given at 3 places in below query

```
Declare
v_columnlist varchar2(32627);
v_noofcolumns number;
Columnnm  varchar2(1000);
Finalcolumns varchar2(32627);
v_count  number:=0;
plsql_block varchar2(32627);

Begin

select LISTAGG(column_name,',') within group (order by column_id),max(column_id) 
into v_columnlist , v_noofcolumns
from user_tab_columns 
where table_name='tablename';

FOR Lcntr IN 1..v_noofcolumns
LOOP

select REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_columnlist,'[^,]+',1,Lcntr)
into Columnnm
from dual;

plsql_block := 'select count(*)  from tablename  where '|| Columnnm || ' is not null ';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE plsql_block into v_count;

IF v_count > 1 THEN 
Finalcolumns:= LTRIM(Finalcolumns ||','||Columnnm,',');

END IF;

END LOOP;

plsql_block := 'select ' || Finalcolumns ||' from tablename ';

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(plsql_block);

END;
```